# java program to find the number of letters of each word in a sentence

Tags: java, arrays, loops, exception

I want to find the number of letters of each word in a sentence. I have tried several times using several codes but never got it. I always shows the error StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception. One of my codes were as follows:

```
    import java.util.*;
    class LengthOfEachWord
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s,a,b;
            int l,x,l1,y=0,now;
            try
            {
                System.out.print("Enter a sentence:");
                s=sc.nextLine();
                l=s.length();
                String arr[]=s.split(" ");
                now=arr.length;
                while(true)
                {
                    x=s.indexOf(' ');
                    a=s.substring(0,x);
                    l1=a.length();
                    System.out.println(a+"="+l1);
                    b=s.substring(x+1,l);
                    s=b;
                    y++;
                    if(now==y)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }//End of while block
            }//End of try block
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error="+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split the word and by the iteration count the length of every element in the array

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence;
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence:");
    sentence = myScanner.nextLine();
    // now split by space
    final String[] sentceComp = sentence.split(" ");
    // loop over the words in sentence
    for (int i = 0; i < sentceComp.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("The word \"" + sentceComp[i] + "\" in the input sentence has " + sentceComp[i].length() + " chars");
    }
}
```

## output:

> Enter a sentence:
>
> java program to find the length of each word in a sentence
>
> The word "java" in the input sentence has 4 chars
>
> The word "program" in the input sentence has 7 chars
>
> The word "to" in the input sentence has 2 chars
>
> The word "find" in the input sentence has 4 chars
>
> The word "the" in the input sentence has 3 chars
>
> The word "length" in the input sentence has 6 chars
>
> The word "of" in the input sentence has 2 chars
>
> The word "each" in the input sentence has 4 chars
>
> The word "word" in the input sentence has 4 chars
>
> The word "in" in the input sentence has 2 chars
>
> The word "a" in the input sentence has 1 chars
>
> The word "sentence" in the input sentence has 8 chars

Comment: Thank you. Can you give a program that is a little more simplified and doesn't make the use of arrays?